# DeferedRender set a true caused problems with a text editor extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, tinymce, extjs3

The problem I have is that I have a "tabpanel" inside a tabpanel and inside a tinyMce editor, the problem is that in I.E. the texteditor don´t shows well because the render event launch to earlier and is painted bigger than necesary, I tried with:

```
      deferredRender:true
```

But this cause colateral damages like not charging data I need before open a tab because I need to send it in an update event.
So what could I do? I tried also with forceLayout:false, but I have the same problem.
Any solution? thanks!

Comment: could you please provide some code snippet for better understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use deferredRender:true, it makes thinks very difficult and all become a crazy XD.